# associative array with two strings

Tags: bash, shell-script

is it possible to loop a simple array with key and value
with a string in the [key] part ?

```
#!/bin/bash -x

wget url://stringlist1
wget url://stringlist2

#cat/sed some stuff ....

declare -A targetarray

loop $resultfromstringlist1
in strlistarray1 # filled with ( aka1 kaka hu3hu blabla )

loop $resultfromstringlist2
in strlistarray2 # filled with ( Thoralf Mirkoslav Pjotr Jan )

i=0;
for e in strlistarray1
do
   targetarray[$e]="${strlistarray2[$i]}"
   ((++i))
done

#wanted output 
echo ${targetarray[aka1]}  -> Thoralf

exit
```

i hope now is more clear

$e stays on $e its not filled with the string from strlist1 array

**with manual setting works** but not with loop
bash version is 4.3

```
#!/bin/bash

unset aaaa
declare -A aaaa

str1="hans"
str2="klaus"

aaaa[$str1]="online";
aaaa[$str2]="offline";

echo ${aaaa[$str1]}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please give an example of what you want to see assigned to which array variables in this example you gave ? You gave constant string "`USER`" to be assigned to the array elements `a[aka_one]` `a[aka_two]` and `a[aka_seven]` I believe you wanted to do something else but can not figure out what.

Comment: @MelBurslan : yes i filled the loops only for explain what i try and show the debug i want to have in array [shortname]=LONGNAME so that i can search for both value and key not for index  ... i updated the first post

Comment: If you're asking what I _think_ you're circuitously asking, yes, in bash 4.0 and later, you can use string indices for "associative" arrays; prior versions only have integer indices.

Comment: @DopeGhoti manual works but not with loop i add a manual version to first post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This demonstrates how to populate and query an associative array `targetarray` with keys and values from two simple arrays `strlistarray1` and `strlistarray2`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a strlistarray1=( aka1 kaka hu3hu blabla )
declare -a strlistarray2=( Thoralf Mirkoslav Pjotr Jan )

declare -A targetarray

i=0
for e in "${strlistarray1[@]}"; do
    targetarray["$e"]="${strlistarray2[i]}";
    ((i++))
done

for e in "${!targetarray[@]}"; do 
    echo $e --- ${targetarray[$e]}
done
```

To fetch the contents of a file (assuming one entry per line), try

```
IFS=$'\n'
declare -a strlistarray1=($(< yourfile))
unset IFS
```

To fetch data from a URL, try

```
IFS=$'\n'
declare -a strlistarray1=($(wget -qO - 'http://yoururl'))
unset IFS
```

(Setting `IFS` is required to avoid problems with fetched data containing spaces. If you're sure your input data doesn't have spaces, as in your question, the two `IFS` statements can be omitted.)

Comment: manual set no problem but not with dynamic fetched strings ....i canot declare staticly the values of strlistarray1 & strlistarray2 i fetch 2 files and generate the stringlists out of the files the extra declare does the thing ... very strange  i fill my strings with 2x extra loops into the -a declared arrays so all will work ...

Comment: @GorgoneImpertinence See updated answer for suggested use of `wget` to assign dynamic data. Maybe this helps.

Comment: thanks ur solution for getting the online datas in the array looks nicer than my version